# Qlikview: Problem of the average duration of the most used subscription modality

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview

Be a subscription video streaming service. There are 3 subscription modalities, A, B, C. You want to calculate the average duration of the modality that has the highest number of subscribers per month.

The next chart show the amount of users by the type of suscription modality.
[image]

I need the expresion to generate a chart that shows the duration of the mode with the highest number of users per month.

I have [the following fictitious data](https://github.com/GuillermoBaldan/test/blob/main/stackoverflow_qlikview-problem.xlsx):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Month` as a dimension on a chart, you can use the expression:

```
=FirstSortedValue(
    Aggr(Avg(Duration), Msuscription, Month),
    -Aggr(Count(user), Msuscription, Month)
)
```

This is sorting by the expression you used to create the chart in your question, and using `-` returns the highest value.